# In Mongoose how declare dynamic Schema

Tags: node.js, schema, mongoose

I'm a newbie to Mongoose and in the official documentation I don't found anything related to what I need.

How can I declare a child schema that is dynamic?

For example:

```
var A = new Schema({
    name        : String,
    subtype     : String,
    description : String
});

var B = new Schema({
    name        : String,
    description : String
});

var C = new Schema({
    name        : String,
    type        : [if(type.value == 'A') then uses Schema-A;
                   if(type.value == 'B') then uses Schema-B;
                  ]
});
```

Hope it makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need this ?

In Javascript you don t need to think about the class of an object.

You just need to know the type when you want to initialize it and when you want to search in MongoDB.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply :D. What I need is accomodate variable fields in a mongoose Subschema, if you known a way to do that can you post an example? No matter if is in the Schema definition stage or in the initialization stage but it could be great if the solution does not lost the goodies of using mongoose (validation, etc).

Comment: Define your schema as the super-set of all possible fields and then use validation middleware to ensure the populated set of fields are valid.

Comment: After digging more on this I realize that I really don't needed for my application ;) thanks.

Comment: You need to think about the class of an object if you are using inheritance from a base class. RegularFoo extends Foo, FancyFoo extends Foo etc. where RegularFoos have different attributes from FancyFoos, while sharing basic Foo attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the type of the custom section of the schema as {} and then validate different structures that flow in. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/aheckmann/2789681). It isn't as nice as having different Schemas set up for the different cases but it should serve the purpose. Essentially, by setting things up this way, you're essentially saying that that part of the document doesn't have a Schema. Think of Schemas as *determinate* parts of the document, and the only determinate part here is the placeholder for the dynamic parts.

You could also, I think, create each different structure as a different schema but stored in the same collection, choosing the appropriate schema upfront. I've never tried that but it should be allowed because of the schema-less nature of the underlying MongoDB.